# Selenium Virtual Frame Buffer on Windows

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a requirement to run a process that itself requires the functionality of the Firefox browser. Currently, I run this process on a laptop, so having Firefox running is not a problem.

However, we would like to move to a server deployment Windows AND Linux. The issue is I can find set up instructions for Linux, but I can't find Windows support or documentation for the same. Can Selenium be run on Windows and if so can anyone point me to some documentation?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I am not clear with the whole question, but for the last part, Yes Selenium can be run on Windows without any issue. You can run Selenium on Windows using any of IE and Firefox. http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: Selenium is just Java.  The way you run it should be pretty much identical across platforms as it all comes down to executing the jre.  How do you run selenium currently?  Maven?  Ant?  What testing framework do you use, JUnit?  TestNG?  Chances are, those will affect more strongly how you run your Selenium builds